# The 1-Norm, the 2-Norm, and the Max-Norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

**Exercise** Find $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$m_1 \|x \|_1 \leq \|x \| \leq m_2 \| x \|_1$$

$$m_3 \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\| \leq m_4 \|x\|_\infty$$

---

For $x = \langle x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^n$, It should be stated that

> $\|x\|_1 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ (Taxicab)

> $\|x\|_\infty = \max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\dots,|x_n|\}$ (Max-Norm)

> $\|x\| = \sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ (Euclidean)

I am not entirely sure how to pick these $m_i$'s at all. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions on a good start to a problem like this?

Comment: I would try to solve $m_1=\frac{||x||}{||x||_1}$ and so on. Also $m_i$ should be real numbers not vectors, right?

Comment: $m_i$ should me positive reals ($\mathbb R^+$) not vectors, $\mathbb R^n.$ If $m_1$ is a vector, then $$m_1\|x\|_1\leq \|x\|$$  doesn’t make any sense - the right side is a real number and the left side is a vector.

Comment: Here's a thought about visualizing the constants.  Draw the "unit balls" for each of the three norms in a low-dimensional space.  Find a constant for the dilation of the unit ball with respect to one norm to enclose (say) the unit ball with respect to the Euclidean norm.  These constants could well vary with the dimension $n$.

Comment: Also, $\|x\|_\infty$ is the maximum of the absolute values of the $x_i,$and you left out the squares in the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @hardmath what is meant by the term "dilation" in this context?

Comment: Emily, start with the case of two variables. The unit circle, also the unit circle in the $\infty$ norm, which is a square; finally, the unit circle in the $1$ norm, which is a square rotated $45^\circ.$  Anyway, get some graph paper and draw some pictures.

Comment: @hardmath your answer makes sense for the righthands side of the inequality, but how are we to interpret the lefthand side? In other words, what is keeping me from picking $m_1 = 0$ and $m_3 = 0$, trivially?

Comment: Briefly, one finds a positive constant $M_1$ sufficiently large that $||x|| \le M_1 ||x||_1$, so that in other words the unit Euclidean ball fits inside a "dilated" by factor $M_1$ copy of the unit 1-norm ball (a "diamond" in two dimensions).  Then $m_1 = 1/M_1$ satisfies $m_1 ||x|| \le ||x||_1$.  A similar argument applies to the $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Note that the exercise statement neglects to require $m_i$ to be positive,  It should say $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ or otherwise convey that these are positive constants.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $\|x\| \ge m_1 \|x\|_1$: Write $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| = \sum_{i=1}^n (|x_i| \cdot 1)$ and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
- $\|x\| \le m_2 \|x\|_1$: Expand the square $\|x\|_1^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\right)^2$ and compare with $\|x\|^2$.
- $\|x\| \le m_4 \|x\|_\infty$: In $\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2}$, bound each $|x_i|$ by $\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}$.
- $\|x\| \ge m_3 \|x\|_\infty$: In $\|x\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2$, note that the sum of nonnegative numbers is at least as large as the maximum.

Comment: For the first bullet point, you ask to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but how is this applicable? $|x_1| \cdot 1$ is a product of two scalars, whereas the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality refers to dot products and norms of vectors.

Comment: @EmilyBurkenhamen Consider the dot product of the vectors $(|x_1|, \ldots, |x_n|)$ and $(1,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: I see now, thank you

Comment: Why can't I just let $m_1 = 0$ and $m_3 = 0$ trivially?

Comment: @EmilyBurkenhamen The problem in your post is not stated well; all the $m_i$ should be strictly positive. See the [definition of norm equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence) where their constants $C$ and $D$ must be positive.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is hard to find $m_1$ and $m_3$ by merely graphing cocentric open "balls," whereas interpreting $m_2$ and $m_4$ is obvious, since we merely find what value of dilation causes each norm to become a superset of the Euclidean ball. That being said,  do you have any advice for interpreting $m_1$ and $m_3$ graphically?